# ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number while mixing VBA with SQL in Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, reportbuilder3.0

I have written a function in the Microsoft Report Builder that determines which table should be used in a select statement for a specific parameter.

It seems my VB Code is right, but when i try to open the Report it throws "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number".

```
Public Function getFieldSQL(level, par_time) as string
    dim result as string
    result = " SELECT     0 AS FIELD_ID, 'Alle ' AS FIELD_ID_show " & vbNewLine & _ 
             " FROM         SYS.DUAL " & vbNewLine & _
             " UNION " & vbNewLine & _
             "SELECT DISTINCT FIELD_ID, to_char(FIELD_ID) || ' - ' || FIELD_bez AS FIELD_ID_show" & vbNewLine & _
             " FROM   " & vbNewLine

   if level = "Specific Level" then
            result = result & " DB.TABLE1 " & vbNewLine
    else
            result = result & " DB.TABLE2 " & vbNewLine
    end if
    result = result & " WHERE TIMES = "& par_time & vbNewLine & _
             " ORDER BY 1 " & vbNewLine
    return result
End Function
```

Here are the two select statements which should be built due to the function:

```
SELECT 0 AS FIELD_ID, 'Alle ' AS FIELD_ID_SHOW
    FROM SYS.DUAL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT FIELD_ID, TO_CHAR(FIELD_ID) || ' - ' || FIELD_BEZ AS FIELD_ID_SHOW
    FROM DB.TABLE1
    WHERE TIMES = par_time
    ORDER BY 1
```

TABLE2 should be used when level is "Specific Level".

```
SELECT 0 AS FIELD_ID, 'Alle ' AS FIELD_ID_SHOW
    FROM SYS.DUAL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT FIELD_ID, TO_CHAR(FIELD_ID) || ' - ' || FIELD_BEZ AS FIELD_ID_SHOW
    FROM DB.TABLE2
    WHERE TIMES = par_time
    ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: this is not vba.. vba function does not use "Return" keyword to return the value. it ueses the function name. there you have your first error! I'm not familiar with oracle but your sql statement seems poorly constructed.

Comment: Okay, i did not know that this is no vba. The sql statement works in PL/SQL. Is it vb? Microsoft says so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i solved the problem with a colleague. It was a problem in the settings of the reportbuilder. The dataset that used the function was still set up for a direct query not for a query through an function.